# Getting blocked response even if status code 200 is returned

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have MVC web app and I am consuming some WEB API with AJAX calls. I try to login, so I send username and password, to get the needed info (token etc.).

```
var loginData = {
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: 'SomeName',
            password: 'SomePass'
        };            

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Token',
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset='utf-8'",
            data: loginData,     
            success: function (response) { // 200 Status Header
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.access_token);
                alert('Success!');
            },
            error: function (response) { // 500 Status Header
                alert('Error!');
            }
        });
```

The problem is - After the request is send, the server **returns** the response with all the informations, but it is somehow blocked.

[It returns status code - 200 with all the information but the response is blocked/aborted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp7de.png)

[Session properties (provided by Fiddler)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTITn.png)